# "Start AUT" and get '5009: AUT start failed No valid Java binary found. Check given JRE binary.?

Tags: macos, jubula

I'm using Jubula on MacOS. When "Start AUT" I get this error:

> 5009: AUT start failed No valid Java binary found. Check given JRE
>   binary.

Is there a solution to fix this problem.
I'm using MacOS Mojave and Jubula 8 .

Answer (score 0):

The reasons for this message could be a lot of problems. It depends on your setup and the how you want to start the application in Jubula.

This message can also be misleading. Since sometimes this message is also shown if some problem with the path to the Application is present.

Make sure your setup is correctly. All paths are correctly set and java is available if you want to start jars.
Also there might be Toolkit specific setup in the AUT configurations. In JavaFX e.g. for starting a jar you must set the path to the java executable as executable and -jar your.jar in the arguments.

For better help more information is needed.